# LiteBD database size limits

Tags: c#, litedb

I don't understand what the limits are on the size of a dataset database, if I have a dataset that takes up 6MB or more, I can store it in a [LiteDB](https://www.litedb.org/) single table?

Comment: They mention a size limit of 1Mb on "documents": https://www.litedb.org/docs/filestorage/ Probably this means 1 single document in a "table" of documents (this is what I would assume) - try it and see! Usually in no-sql db's like this you have collections of documents rather than "tables".

Comment: So ... if you are trying to represent a "table" as a 6MB document then you also have your answer ... but you still have ways to use their FileStorage api to work with your document.